# Add effect to crosshair cursor

Tags: jquery, css, cursor

I have my cursor set to crosshair whenever it's over a div set to `width: 100%` and `height: 520px`  and I also want to achieve the effect in the image below but I honestly don't know how?

Those lines have to follow the cursor wherever it goes inside that container.

I searched the internet high and low and couldn't find anything. Any ideas?
Can it be realized with jquery?

[image]

UPDATE:
I managed to do this : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/wnmcgdwf/3/)

```
$(document).bind('mousemove', function(e){
    $('#right').css({
       left:  e.pageX + 20,
       top:   e.pageY
    });

});
```

Comment: That's not possible with the default crosshair cursor. Use cursor image

Comment: @faizahmed I managed to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/wnmcgdwf/

Comment: I meant that one cannot edit the cursor's shape. Of course you can use jQuery to achieve the results what OP wants

Comment: @faizahmed well, I'm not looking to change the cursor shape, just add the lines on the same axes and to follow it wherever like in my example but I'm stuck with what I have in the jsfiddle.

Comment: @faizahmed I managed to place the bottom line too http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/wnmcgdwf/3/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wnmcgdwf/4/

Comment: @reuelab I could to that myself but the thing is that I need those lines to be 100% like in my example, I could set them to a width/height of 2000px or something like it to simulate the full width/height but is there another way?

Comment: @reuelab like so: http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/wnmcgdwf/6/

Comment: ahh, i see .. hmm i can't think of another way except jquery

Comment: @reuelab well, I think i'll just have to do it like that till i find another way around it...anyway, thank you :)

Comment: or maybe using css through ::before and ::after pseudo selectors

Comment: @reuelab I am more happy with jquery and attached 1px containers cause of compatibility with oldies. It's working fine anyway with our mixed version, thanks, if you want you can place your version as an answer and i'll mark it. ^^